# ItunesConnect: can't use production build for TestFlight

Tags: app-store-connect

I got an app accepted by Apple that i'm going to release soon. The current state of the app is "Waiting developer release", I wanted to invite some external tester using TestFlight so I added the accepted build of my app to the TestFlight build but I keep getting the following e-mail from Apple:

> Your app "***" (Apple ID: ***) has one or more issues Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent submission for
>   "***". To process your submission, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> Invalid or Non-Increasing CFBundleShortVersionString - The value
>   specified in the bundle's Info.plist file for the key
>   CFBundleShortVersionString must be a string consisting of at most
>   three dot-separated components, where each component is composed only
>   of the digits 0 through 9. For example, any of the following are
>   syntactically valid values for CFBundleShortVersionString: "1.0",
>   "4.2.1", "3.46", "1.112.0"; whereas the following are all
>   syntactically invalid: "1.4.0.0.0.0.5", "GX5", "3.4.2b6", "2.6GM",
>   "1.0 (Gold)", "-3.6". Additionally, each updated version of the same
>   application must have a CFBundleShortVersionString that increases
>   relative to that of the previous version that was actually made
>   available for sale on the iTunes Store. For example, if a
>   previously-available version had a CFBundleShortVersionString of
>   "1.4", then any of the following would be acceptable as the next
>   update: "1.4.1", "1.4.332", "1.5"; but all of the following (though
>   syntactically valid) would be unacceptable: "1.4", "1.3", "1.3.9",
>   "0.9". For more information about the CFBundleShortVersionString key
>   and the Info.plist file, see Apple's Runtime Configuration Guidelines
>   at
>   http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/index.html

Why can't I use the same build for both production and TestFlight? As I already said the app has not been released yet so it seems strange that I can't use the already uploaded build..